# List seems to be an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Code:

```
def calcPossibleMoves(grid):
    possibleMoves = []
    for x in range(9):
        if grid[x] == 0:
            possibleMoves.append(x)
    return possibleMoves
```

Comment: We would need to know what is being passed to the function (i.e. the value of `grid`).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `grid` argument; the only place you used subscripting was when you did `grid[x]`, so the problem is in code you didn't show; the code that calls your function and provides an `int` instead of a sequence of some sort.

Comment: While what you say isn't wrong, it's unfortunately also not an answer IMO.